# Can I vertically align images within a marquee tag

Tags: html, marquee

I would like to align vertically the images within the marquee tag (and only the images - not the whole marquee). Is it possible to achieve this?

```
        <Marquee Behavior="scroll" Scrolldelay="100">
            <b>Amsterdam, Pays-Bas</b>: 26&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/10d.png"> &#149; <b>Bangkok, Tha&#239;lande</b>: 31&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/02d.png"> &#149; <b>Beijing, Chine</b>: 26&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/10n.png"> &#149; <b>Berlin, Allemagne</b>: 27&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/09d.png"> &#149; <b>Brussels, Belgique</b>: 26&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01d.png"> &#149; <b>Buenos Aires, Argentine</b>: 4&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/50d.png"> &#149; <b>Copenhagen, Danemark</b>: 24&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/04d.png"> &#149; <b>Dodoma, Tanzanie</b>: 28&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01d.png"> &#149; <b>Ha Noi, Vietnam</b>: 28&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/10n.png"> &#149; <b>Helsinki, Finlande</b>: 19&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/04d.png"> &#149; <b>Hong Kong, Hong-Kong</b>: 30&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01n.png"> &#149; <b>Jakarta, Indon&#233;sie</b>: 27&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/11n.png"> &#149; <b>Johannesburg, Afrique du Sud</b>: 20&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/09d.png"> &#149; <b>Kampala, Ouganda</b>: 25&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/03d.png"> &#149; <b>Kuala Lumpur, Malaisie</b>: 27&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/11n.png"> &#149; <b>La Paz, Bolivie</b>: 1&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01n.png"> &#149; <b>Lima, P&#233;rou</b>: 17&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/02d.png"> &#149; <b>Lisbon, Portugal</b>: 25&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/02d.png"> &#149; <b>Los Angeles, Etats-Unis</b>: 20&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01n.png"> &#149; <b>Macau, Macao</b>: 30&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/02n.png"> &#149; <b>Madrid, Espagne</b>: 32&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01d.png"> &#149; <b>Manila, Philippines</b>: 24&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/11n.png"> &#149; <b>Melbourne, Australie</b>: 14&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/10n.png"> &#149; <b>Mexico City, Mexique</b>: 14&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/04n.png"> &#149; <b>Miami, Etats-Unis</b>: 27&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/10d.png"> &#149; <b>Montreal, Canada</b>: 19&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/03d.png"> &#149; <b>New Delhi, Inde</b>: 38&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/50d.png"> &#149; <b>New York, Etats-Unis</b>: 21&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/50d.png"> &#149; <b>Oslo, Norv&#232;ge</b>: 25&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/03d.png"> &#149; <b>Paris, France</b>: 24&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/04d.png"> &#149; <b>Reykjavik, Islande</b>: 13&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/04d.png"> &#149; <b>Rio de Janeiro, Br&#233;sil</b>: 17&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/04d.png"> &#149; <b>Roma, Italie</b>: 30&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01d.png"> &#149; <b>Santiago, Chili</b>: 4&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/50n.png"> &#149; <b>Seoul, Cor&#233;e du Sud</b>: 27&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/50n.png"> &#149; <b>Singapore, Singapour</b>: 29&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/11n.png"> &#149; <b>Stockholm, Su&#232;de</b>: 24&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01d.png"> &#149; <b>Sydney, Australie</b>: 14&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01n.png"> &#149; <b>Tokyo, Japon</b>: 22&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/09n.png"> &#149; <b>Vienna, Autriche</b>: 30&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/03d.png"> &#149; <b>Washington D.C., Etats-Unis</b>: 18&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/50d.png"> &#149; <b>Wellington, Nouvelle-Z&#233;lande</b>: 8&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01n.png"> &#149; <b>Windhoek, Namibie</b>: 23&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/01d.png"> &#149; <b>Zurich, Suisse</b>: 26&#176;C <img src="assets/meteo_icons/03d.png">
        </Marquee>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 Marquee img {
    vertical-align:middle
    }
```